# Unable to access file directory and files Centos 7

Tags: linux, directory, permissions, centos7, cd

+x Permission is provided for user and directory is owned by the user.

```
drwxr-xr-x.  3 www-data www-data   19 Nov 30 10:41 www
```

Still, I am unable to access the directory.

www-data is Nginx and PHP-fpm user. When I try `su www-data` I can't access any directory inside `/var` although I can do `cd /var`.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.

Comment: You should be able to click the *close(1)* button to see the reason. However, the Stack Exchange network does not want you to know, so they don't reveal the reason to you. No one understands why. It is another policy or UX bug we have been trying to get fixed for years. Would you mind filing a bug at [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if this account has a login access, by checking items in /etc/passwd.
If it has a "nologin", you can't login with this us